# How to register a Plugin in Zend Framework application.ini?

Tags: zend-framework

I am still very new to Zend Framework and I am stuck with creating a Plugin. I would like to create a Sidebar to display Visitor Stats which should be visible on all pages. I therefore decided to create a Plugin and integrate this in my layout file. I have already a Plugin in there, called Application_Plugin_CategoriesNavigation

My Plugins sits under 
application/plugins/Sidebar.php
application/plugins/CategoriesNavigation

In my application.ini, I have entered the following:

```
application.ini
resources.frontController.plugins.categoriesnavigation = "Application_Plugin_CategoriesNavigation"
resources.frontController.plugins.sidebar = "Application_Plugin_Sidebar"
```

My Plugin Class right now

```
//My Plugin Class:
class Application_Plugin_Sidebar extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{ 
     public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
     {      
    echo "Just a test";
     }
}
```

Unfotunately I get the following Error Message:

> Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message
>   'Plugin by name 'Sidebar' was not found in the registry; used paths:
>   Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_: Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/
>   ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper_: ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper/
>   Zend_View_Helper_:

What am I doing wrong? The Navigation Plugin works fine and looks the same, but why does it not work with the second Plugin?

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your config:

```
appnamespace               = "Application"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I had this already in the application.ini and it changed nothing. Any other idea what it could be? I integrate jQuery in my boostrap file, could this be the reason? But why would the other Plugin than work?

Answer (score -1):

I am such an idiot, my mistake was how I called it up in the Layout File. I used echo $this->sidebar(); , but this causes the Error. To call up the Plugin in the Layout file you have to use:

```
<?php echo $this->layout()->sidebar; ?>
```

Very sorry for this silly mistake.

Comment: You're mixing controller plugins with view helpers, which makes both your question and answer very confusing.